DebeziumException "The connector previously stopped while taking a snapshot, but now the connector is configured to never allow snapshots"
I am using debezium in distributed mode to push the cdc events of mssql db to kafka topics.
Command: %KAFKA_HOME%\bin\windows\connect-distributed.bat

Debezium starts fine, I deployed the connector and it synced tables and pushed records to kafka perfectly fine. But if I stop the %KAFKA_HOME%\bin\windows\connect-distributed.bat and restart, ideally it should resume from the last offset where I had stopped earlier but it gives an exception:
DebeziumException: The connector previously stopped while taking a snapshot, but now the connector is configured to never allow snapshots. Reconfigure the connector to use snapshots initially or when needed.

Connector configuration:
{
    "name": "mssql-dbz-connector", 
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector", 
        "database.hostname": "***", 
        "database.port": "1433", 
        "database.user": "***", 
        "database.password": "***", 
        "database.names": "***",
        "database.encrypt": "false",
        "topic.prefix": "***",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "***",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "***",
        "snapshot.mode": "schema_only"
    }
}

Exception:
ERROR [mssql-dbz-connector|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=mssql-dbz-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:212)
io.debezium.DebeziumException: The connector previously stopped while taking a snapshot, but now the connector is configured to never allow snapshots. Reconfigure the connector to use snapshots initially or when needed.
        at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.validateAndLoadSchemaHistory(BaseSourceTask.java:97)
        at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnectorTask.start(SqlServerConnectorTask.java:108)
        at io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask.start(BaseSourceTask.java:240)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.initializeAndStart(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractWorkerSourceTask.run(AbstractWorkerSourceTask.java:77)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:236)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[2024-05-19 23:48:29,610] INFO [mssql-dbz-connector|task-0] Stopping down connector (io.debezium.connector.common.BaseSourceTask:398)


if connect was stopped forcefully the latest offset may not have been saved and still contain snapshot flag set to "true" ... you should publish a message into the offset topic with that flag removed or publish a message with an empty value and start from scratch (you may want to purge the data topics also if you want to start from scratch)

@acristu We have migrated from debezium 2.0.0 to 2.6.1 and we were using snapshot.mode=schema_only.
This beahaviour works fine in 2.0.0 but issue is coming in 2.6.0 as I can see, schema_only has been deprecated in 2.6.0. Looks like these validations are added in 2.6.0. Which mode is equivalent to schema_only in 2.6.0? "no_data" or any other mode? Documentation is not so clear

I'm not using 2.6 yet so did not test this for myself, but  looks like no_data

I am using 2.6.1 version and this issue is a known issue and will be released in 2.6.2 and it is still not released.
Issue: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-7780
